# Using Ruby to execute Powershell command in Git Hooks

Tags: ruby, git, powershell, nunit

I am using Git on Windows and trying to include unit testing in the workflow. If the commit message contain a keyword. The *commit-msg* hook will trigger Powershell command to run some Nunit tests.

This is my ruby code in the hook

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
message_file = ARGV[0]
message = File.read(message_file)

puts "The commit message is " + message

$regex = /(#runtest)/

if $regex.match(message)
    exec 'powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Command {RunNunitTestCase}'
end
```

However when I commit a changes, the result is like below. The exec line was run but do nothing.

```
PS D:\testfolder> git commit -am '#runtest'
The commit message is #runtest
[authorupdate b14878d] 123
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
```

I am new to ruby and powershell. Feel free to comment if this workflow is feasible or you have a better approach.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The curly bracket needs to be escaped.

```
exec "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Command & \{RunNunitTestCase\}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the exact script with the exec line being:

```
exec 'powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Command gps'
```

and it did print out the output of `gps` when I did `git commit -m "#runtest"`

So it does run the command and it does work.

Make sure that whatever you are executing does work. Grab the powershell line and try it out on commandline directly.

Comment: Thank you @manojlds. I found the problem on the curly bracket. It need to be escaped. `exec "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Command & \{RunNunitTestCase\}"` Or I can simply remove the brackets in this case.

Comment: @seanbun - If it helped you, you can accept this as answer ( the tick to the left)